# Uses of Present Perfect

Tags: present-tense

I have a book that says "we use present perfect for something that happened in the past without a **specific time** and still continue until now". Then what should I use if it happened in the past with a *specific time* and still continue until now?

Comment: sample sentence would be `Nobody has ever climbed that mountain.`

Comment: On your question, you must use present perfect.

Comment: related: [Present simple and present perfect in this context](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124011/present-simple-and-present-perfect-in-this-context)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is correct: "has died" or "died"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63256/which-is-correct-has-died-or-died)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to consider that the **present perfect** represents a completed action that could have taken place at any time in the past, right up to the present.  If you say

> I **have seen** that movie

I know that you've viewed that movie at some time, but I don't know exactly when.  It could have been three days ago, or you could mean that you have *just* seen that movie, having walked out of the theater moments before.

If you're talking about a singular completed action, then it's over and done with, and it can't continue until now.  If you want to talk about ongoing action, you may use the **present perfect progressive**:

> Q: Did you do your homework?
>   A: No, I **have been watching** television.

You started watching television at some past time, but I don't know exactly when, and I don't know when you stopped.  It could have been any time after you started, including right up to now.

Comment: So that means I should use "Ive been working here since 2015" instead of "I was working.."?

Comment: @user178049 Yes, *I was working here* [in 2015]" talks about an ongoing action in the past, i.e., not a singular event but action over an interval, but that interval is over.  With *I've been working here since 2015*, the interval continues up to the present moment.